# Getting error in react after installing fontawesome through npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

i have installed fontawesome by following these steps by visiting their website.

npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core

npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons

npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome

and now am getting this error

./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/lib/runtime/RefreshUtils.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\practice site\javascript\REACT\Codingworld\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules@pmmmwh\react-refresh-webpack-plugin\lib\runtime\RefreshUtils.js'

Help me to solve my error

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that it's looking for a file `RefreshUtils.js` in the directory `C:\Users\HP\Desktop\practice site\javascript\REACT\Codingworld\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules@pmmmwh\react-refresh-webpack-plugin\lib\runtime` but doesn't find it.

This file is part of the npm package `@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin`.

It could be that you previously installed this package, or that this package is a dependency for another package you're using (e.g. react-scripts).

Your question doesn't include sufficient information, such as the content of your `package.json` file, and specifying which command is giving the error.

There could be various reasons causing the error:

- Running the command from the wrong folder

  In this case, navigate to the correct folder in your terminal, then run the command.
- Issues in your dependencies

  In this case, given that you have a `package.json` file in your project folder, reinstall all your dependencies:

  1. Delete the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file
  2. Run `npm cache clean`
  3. Run `npm install`

Given that you're running the command from the correct folder and your dependencies are up-to-date, the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one. I hope to solve it. if it solves please comment on my answer.

> `install font-awesome for react`